# getting error: use of undeclared type when I push pod to private cocoapods repo

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I can successfully build, run my tests schemes. I tried pushing changes to my pod's repo by doing:

```
pod repo push my-private-cocoapods Device.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
- ERROR | [Device/Phone] xcodebuild:  Device/Phone/Classes/Views/StackProvider.swift:13:42: error: use of undeclared type 'MacAddress'
```

Yet `MacAddress` is a `public` type.

I've restarted my mac, cleaned build, cleaned derive data, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a combination of:

- One of subpods had a dependency on another subpod which was from the same pod
- I was **not** running `pod lib lint`. I was relying on a test scheme and was just running tests through Xcode on the vanilla example app.

Basically my `Device/Phone` subpod was dependent on `Device/Core` subpod. I needed to update my `Phone` podspec.
Currently it's like this:

```
s.subspec 'Core' do |subspec|
    subspec.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 4.5.0'
    subspec.dependency 'RxCocoa', '~> 4.5.0'
    subspec.source_files = 'Phone/Classes/*.{h,m,swift}', 'Phone/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
    subspec.test_spec 'Tests' do |test_spec|
      test_spec.source_files = 'Phone/Tests/*.swift'
    end
  end

  s.subspec 'Phone' do |subspec|
    subspec.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 4.5.0'
    subspec.source_files = 'Phone/Classes/*.{h,m,swift}', 'Phone/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
    subspec.resources = 'Phone/Classes/*.{xib}', 'Phone/Classes/**/*.{xib}'
    subspec.test_spec 'Tests' do |test_spec|
      test_spec.dependency 'Device', '~> 1.0.7'
      test_spec.source_files = 'Phone/Tests/*.swift'
    end
end
```

The only thing I had to add was a new dependency to my `Phone` spec's dependency list:

```
subspec.dependency 'Device/Core',
```

And then I was able to do push my new spec.

```
pod repo push my-private-cocoapods Device.podspec --allow-warnings --verbose
```